# mongodb wt file corrupt issue, can not query few documents

Tags: mongodb, linux, files

I have a mongodb cluster with 3 shards and no replication 
The problem is one of the shards has a bad disk and because of which some files show input/output error when trying to read

```
[root@mongodb2 b0]# md5sum collection-700-3655945817504191327.wt
md5sum: collection-700-3655945817504191327.wt: Input/output error
```

If I try to use wt to salvage the file that too fails

I know exactly which documents are corrupt , but I am helpless because I can not delete or update these documents. Any find() or remove() command on these documents causes entire mongo shard to get killed.

How can I recover this data

Comment: this is not MongoDB related. You need first to fix your I/O errors on VM (or physical hardware) and filesystem level. What says `dmesg`? What filesystem do you use? What's the output of filesystem check? What's in /var/log/messages about I/O and filesystems errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok we "fixed" the issue or atleast solved the problem of Mongo crashing

The wt collection file was corrupt and was not readable. 
We run ddrescue and got rid of the bad sections in the file

```
ddrescue -n -e1 /database/mongocluster/shard2/b0/collection-72--3831537583791950739.wt RecoveredFiles/collection-72--3831537583791950739.wt RecoveredFiles/collection-72--3831537583791950739.wt.log
```

And then run wt to salvage the file

```
./wt  -v -h /database/mongocluster/shard2/b0 -C "extensions=[./ext/compressors/snappy/.libs/libwiredtiger_snappy.so]" -R salvage collection-72--3831537583791950739.wt
```

Thats it!!. The bad documents could not be recovered, but never mind I can regenerate that data from my app. Most importantly the mongo server does not crash. Hopefully mongodb will improve the logic in the newer versions. Crashing the db on any single I/O error is not very helpful